# Pygame randomly move enemies

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to send the rocks into random positions,i tried:
self.x += random.randint(-5, 5)
but this is not good because every iteration of the main loop, the random number is recalculated and this creates a flickering effect that, besides being horrible, blocks the right angle of the rock. How can I fix it?
I just want, starting from the high center of the screen, that the rocks go down with a random angle, then I would implement some bounces and so create my video game, but I'm stuck in that point.
it's the first time I write on this forum so if I do something wrong I apologize in advance.

[I want this random angle for the rocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWnJQ.png)

[image]

This is my code:

```
import pygame
import random
import time
import math

pygame.init()

display_width = 600
display_height = 500
screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (display_width, display_height) )
fps = 60
font_ubuntumono = pygame.font.SysFont('ubuntumono', 50, True)
rock = pygame.image.load('cave-painting.png').convert_alpha()
rock_width = rock.get_width()
rock_height = rock.get_height()
player = pygame.image.load('wizard.png').convert_alpha()

def initialize():
    global speed_rock, rocks, playerX, playerY
    speed_rock = 2
    playerX = display_width//2
    playerY = 400
    rocks = []
    rocks.append( RockClass() )

class RockClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = display_width//2
        self.y = 0

    def continueDraw(self, a, b):
        self.x += **???**
        self.y += speed_rock
        screen.blit( rock, (self.x, self.y) )

    def collision(self, player, playerX, playerY):
        tolerability = 5
        right_player = playerX + player.get_width() - tolerability
        left_player = playerX + tolerability
        up_player = playerY + tolerability
        right_rock = self.x + rock_width
        left_rock = self.x
        down_rock = self.y + rock_height

        #check collision
        if down_rock > up_player and 
           ( ( left_player < left_rock and left_rock < right_player) or 
               ( right_player > right_rock and right_rock > left_player) ):
            #delete the rock from the screen
            self.x = 5000

initialize()

def update():
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.Clock().tick(fps)

def drawThings():
    #draw background
    screen.fill ( (255, 255, 255) )

    #draw rocks
    for rock2 in rocks:
        rock2.continueDraw(210, 210)

    #draw the player
    screen.blit( player, (playerX, playerY) )

running = True
#main loop
while running:

    #event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():

        #move player
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX -= 30
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX += 30

        #quit
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    #to generate infinite rocks
    if rocks[-1].y > 10:
        rocks.append( RockClass() )

    #check the player-rock collision
    for rock2 in rocks:
        rock2.collision(player, playerX, playerY)

    #bordo alto
    if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    if playerX >= 600:
        playerX = 600

    #update screen
    drawThings()
    update()
```

Comment: You need to create a random angle when you initialise each rock, then move the rock in that direction on every tick and account for bouncing off the sides

Comment: Thanks for reply,I can't figure out how to move the rock in the direction of the angle.

Comment: Can you please post the original code? This code is not executable.

Comment: what do you mean for original code? I tried to replicate various games and now I was trying to do this on my own, so this is the original code, I'm not copying it. EDIT: maybe you can't run it because you have not the resources(the images).I posted the enitre code, idk :/

Comment: @C-Gian No,  `rocks` is not defined in global namespace, because `global  rocks` is missing. `rock` is multiply used. First it is a `pygame.Surface` object, later it is a `Rcok` object. That causes an error in `screen.blit( rock, (self.x, self.y) )`

Comment: C-Gian: Your code looks complete, so the only thing missing is the `wizard.png` image file. My advice is, when you post stuff here like this, it would be better to include links for other to download the images or for you to replace them with something else (like say a square or rectangle) int he code before posting it. This will allow other to run (and possibly fix) it.

Comment: @Rabbid76 sorry you were right,I fixed it!

Comment: @martineau Thanks for the advice, I hope the site where I got the pictures is okay: ROCK - https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/cave-painting_925141?term=rock&page=1&position=58  WIZARD- https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/wizard_477154?term=wizard&page=1&position=8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to generate a random speed for the x axis by [`random.uniform(a, b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html) in the constructor of `Rock`:

```py
class Rock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = display_width//2
        self.y = 0
        self.speed_x = random.uniform(-2, 2)
```

Add `self.speed_x` to `self.x` in `continueDraw`:

```py
class Rock:
    # [...]

    def continueDraw(self, a, b):
        self.x += self.speed_x
        self.y += speed_rock
        screen.blit( rock_img, (self.x, self.y) )
```

---

I recommend to use [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) respectively [`colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) for the collision detection:

```py
class Rock:
    # [...]

    def collision(self, player, playerX, playerY):

        tolerability = 5
        player_rect = pygame.Rect(playerX+tolerability, playerY,
                                  player.get_width()-2*tolerability, player.get_height())
        rock_rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, rock_width, rock_height)

        #check collision
        if player_rect.colliderect(rock_rect):
            #delete the rock from the screen
            self.x = 5000
```